# why need de-correlated signal for measuring phase noise in laser

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, phase

when measuring phase noise from a laser by using heterodyne method , we will get the output signal as de-correlated. why we using de-correlated output for phase noise mesurement. how it is related to power spectral density?

Comment: You're asking two separate questions: one, why does the output have to be decorrelated, and two, how is "it" (presumably phase noise) related to power spectral density.  StackExchange likes clear, focused questions.  I suggest that you _edit this question_ to remove the second part, and if you cannot find out how phase noise is related to power spectral density with a web search, _ask that as its own question_.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't measure absolute phase -- you can only measure the phase difference between your unit under test and a reference.

If you have a reference that's perfectly correlated to your unit under test, it's like taking 1000 rulers and measuring each one *against itself*, then deciding they're all perfect.

So you have to make sure that your reference isn't correlated with your unit under test.  I'm not sure how you'd do that with lasers, but with RF equipment it means not only using the best oscillator you can build as a reference, it also means making sure that the signal from the unit under test can't bleed into your reference oscillator and accidentally phase lock it to the unit under test.

Comment: (+1) A potentially distracting comment from the main point: there is the "3-Cornered Hat Method" to measure phase noise when you can't build a better oscillator as a reference--- the "what do you do" when you finally want to measure your phase noise on the best oscillator. Still in this case, each of the three are decorrelated references.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at one coefficient of the correlation

$$c_l = \mathbb{E} \left[ x_k x_{k+l}^*  e^{1j (\theta_k - \theta_l)}\right]$$

$$c_l = \mathbb{E} \left[ z_{k,l}  e^{1j (\theta_k - \theta_l)}\right]$$

$\theta_k - \theta_{k+l} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, l \sigma^2)$

The only way to get a non-zero $c_l$ for $l \ne 0$, is to have $z_{k,l}$ correlated with, $w = e^{1j \mathcal{N}(0, l\sigma^2)}$. The $w$ is independent from $x$ so the only way to get a correlation is if $w$ has non-zero mean, as $l$ increases $w$ approaches a the uniform distribution over the unit circle, then any existing correlation in the input signal will vanish.